# mail reading in php with imap

Tags: php, email, imap

i have read the mail in php with imap_fetchbody() and decode it with imap_qprint().

```
$body = imap_fetchbody($mbox, $no, 1);
$body = imap_qprint($body);
```

but there is difference between original mail and output mail

Original mail:

> Plain Text
>
> This is a testing mail to check
>
> first second third fourth fifth sixth Home
>
> this is yellow background
>
> website: http://bizved.com
>
> testing of quote
>
> Thank you  Hiren Manek Bhuved Solutions

output mail

> Plain Text
>
> This is a testing mail to check
>
> first second third fourth fifth sixth Home
>
> this is yellow background
>
> website:�http://bizved.com
>
> testing of�quote
>
> Thank you �Hiren Manek Bhuved Solutions

can anybody gives solution?
thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to take care of the character encoding of the email when you display it.

Comment: thanks hakre. i have found the solution of this. i have character encoding error

Comment: Try https://github.com/MonstaApps/PHP-IMAP-Fetcher. Pipe or fetch emails, log to MySQL, and save attachments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have make the following solution as mail headers already its character set.

```
$st = imap_fetchstructure($mbox, $no); 
$part = $st->parts[$partno];
$body = imap_fetchbody($mbox, $no, $partno);
$body = imap_qprint($body);
$charset = 'UTF-8';
if(!empty($part->parameters)){
    for ($k = 0, $l = count($part->parameters); $k < $l; $k++) {
        $attribute = $part->parameters[$k];
        if($attribute->attribute == 'CHARSET'){
            $charset = $attribute->value;
        }
    }
}
//echo $charset;
$bodytext = mb_convert_encoding($body,'UTF-8',$charset);
```

This not full solution. It's only for character encoding. Mail has different parts for plain text, html text, attachments, etc. for that you should have different handling for each type.

Answer (score 0):

I always had the same problem with imaps. I'dont guarantee for anything but you may want to give this a try:

```
function utf8_imap_header_decode($str)
{
    $tmp = imap_mime_header_decode($str);
    if (!mb_check_encoding($tmp[0]->text, 'UTF-8'))
        return utf8_encode($tmp[0]->text);

    return $tmp[0]->text;
}

function utf8_imap_body_decode($str)
{
    return utf8_encode(quoted_printable_decode($str));
}
```