# How to fetch a gmail email and display it as it is shown in gmail

Tags: php

I made a program to using php to download email from gmail and save to html file.
everything works file, its connect, downloading mail, downloading attachment, downloading embedded mails and it is also saving to html files and all works fine BUT only SOME mails comes like:

**Example 1:**

```
--_008_8BDE32B1FDB5C947B54F92503EC9934F015611E6glmrsvrmail1gil_ Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="_000_8BDE32B1FDB5C947B54F92503EC9934F015611E6glmrsvrmail1gil_" --_000_8BDE32B1FDB5C947B54F92503EC9934F015611E6glmrsvrmail1gil_ Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 RGVhciBSb3NlLA0KDQpHcmVldGluZ3MgZnJvbSBHaWxpIExhbmthbmZ1c2hp IE1hbGRpdmVzIQ0KDQpXZSBhcmUgZGVsaWdodGVkIHRvIGNvbmZpcm0geW91
```

**Example 2:**
in Gmail it shows with colorful and HTML but here it will come all the text in one like but no html & color

**Example 3:**

```
N§’çè®êßjËZžÌ®(î²ÜžÛh’z0†Œ&¹ÈpŠY\¢Ëf{‰à†+
```

**Example 4:**

```
------_=_NextPart_002_01CE2076.4A2A4F64 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 RGVhciBSb3NlLA0KDQogDQoNClRoaXMgaXMgbXkgb2ZmaWNlIGVtYWlsIGFkZHJlc3MuIEVuY2xv c2VkIGRvY3VtZW50cyBhcyByZXF1aXJlZC4gQWxzbyBlbmNsb3NlZCBteSBjb25maXJtZWQgdGlj a2V0IGZvciB5b3VyIGZ1cnRoZXIgYWN0aW9ucywgcmVxdWVzdCB5b3UgdG8gYXJyYW5nZSBhaXJw
```

I am using the following way top download the mail, please it is coming for only some mails
NOTE: I have no issue with attachments..

```
function read_all_parts($mbox,$uid)
{
global $mime,$ret_info,$enc;
$mime = array("text","multipart","message","application","audio","image","video","other","unknow");
$enc  = array("7BIT","8BIT","BINARY","BASE64","QUOTED-PRINTABLE","OTHER","base64");
$struct = imap_fetchstructure($mbox, $uid );
$ret_info = array();


$ret_info = $this->scan($struct->parts,0);
return $ret_info;
}

$structure = imap_fetchstructure($mbox, $message_id);
$mailDivided= $mailObj->read_all_parts($mbox,$message_id);

if(count($mailDivided)!=0){
    /* ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */
    $plainText = 1;
    foreach ($mailDivided as $key=>$parts)  {
        if($parts['pid']=='1.2' && $parts['encoding']=='QUOTED-PRINTABLE'):
            $plainText = '1.2'; # which means this is contains html text
        endif;

        if($parts['pid']=='1.2' && $parts['encoding']=='7BIT'):
            $plainText = '1.2'; # which means this is contains html text
        endif;

        if($parts['pid']=='1.2' && $parts['encoding']=='8BIT'):
            $plainText = '1.2'; # which means this is contains html text
        endif;

        if($parts['pid']=='1.1.2' && $parts['encoding']=='QUOTED-PRINTABLE'):
            $plainText = '1.1.2'; # which means this is contains html text
        endif;

        if($parts['pid']=='2' && $parts['encoding']=='QUOTED-PRINTABLE'):
            $plainText = '2'; # which means this is contains html text
        endif;
    }
    /* ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */        
    $mymail = imap_fetchbody($mbox,$message_id,$plainText);
    if(imap_base64($mymail)){
        print "This is imap_base64 <br>";
        $mymailBody = imap_base64($mymail);
        $mymailBody =  nl2br($mymailBody);

    }else if (imap_qprint($mymail)){
        print "This is imap_qprint <br>";
        $mymailBody = imap_qprint($mymail);

    }else{
        if ($plainTex==1){
            print "This is nl2br <br>";
            $mymailBody =  nl2br($mymail);
        }else{
            print "This is quoted_printable_decode <br>";
            $mymailBody = quoted_printable_decode($mymail);
        }
    }
    /* ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */
}else{
    print "This is encodingMailbody <br>";
    $mymail = imap_fetchbody($mbox,$message_id,'1');
    $mymailBody = $mailObj->encodingMailbody($mymail,$structure->encoding);
    $mymailBody = nl2br($mymailBody);
}
```

I have been checking and trying all the possible things, nothing is helping me.

Comment: Perhaps because the colors are not defined in the HTML, but in external stylesheets?

Comment: @yvytty This is a hotel reservation system I have made, lots of staff will use this and I dont want to give gmail and it will be uncontrollable.
2. It is like a tiket system, system will identify and when a email is revived it will update the customer profile with email, so staff can check the pending mails.
3. I really dont understand how outlook and other offline programs are showing the mails nicely

Comment: @yvytty ok let me explain detail ;-)
A travel company with 200, management can not monitor what is going on with this 200 staff when they are communicating with clients.
So the system use just 1 email address and clients will never no individual emails of staff and they dont have and we dont give individual emails address. when staff send a mail out it will go from xxx@company.com and guest also will reply to xxx@company.com what my software does is it will identify client Mr.abc is belongs to staff Miss.xyz.

Comment: @yvytty and so management know now Miss.xyz has to reply to Mr.abc and management and other staff will know what is going on. All the staff will have separate username and password for backend to login. Thats the idea and system is now upand running and working fine. now only problem some emails are not formatted nicely. Other important thing is they use in-house server that is super fast ;-).

Comment: Why not just use a ticket system?

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything common about the emails that break versus those that don't? At first glance it seems that the character set maybe different.

A related post is here:
[mail reading in php with imap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462212/mail-reading-in-php-with-imap)

Also, I would try looking at the email header to see if they are formatted differently since different senders structure the email header differently.

Comment: Sorry, I have been trying all
This did not work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462212/mail-reading-in-php-with-imap/16881229

Comment: Looks like no answer to my problem